# Why doesn't this mark work in multimask mudblazor?

Tags: c#, mask, mudblazor

I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
MultiMask mask = new MultiMask("00 0000-0000",  
    new MaskOption("0800", "0000 000 0000", @"^(0[8-9])"),
    new MaskOption("9 digits", "00 00000-0000", @"^(1[1-9][2-9][6-9])")
);
```

Typing `08`; expected 0800 mask, works!
Typing `11 98`; expected 9 digits mask, doesn't work

Test here
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkQHaLlIYxaDmVwI

Here is my discussion in GitHub:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/7206